# How To Display Images with Zend?

Tags: image, zend-framework, using

Please help, I'm currently learn to build site with Zend but still can't displaying the images at the view.phtml

**I'm wrote at my  Form_PersonilCreate.php :**

```
$this->setAction('/data/personil/create')
        ->setMethod('post');

    //Item input untuk gambar
    $images = new Zend_Form_Element_File('images');
    $images->setDestination(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../public/images/personil");
    $images->addValidator('Count', false, 1)
            ->addValidator('IsImage')
            ->addValidator('size', false, '204800')
            ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg, png, gif, jpeg')
            ->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array(
                    'minwidth' => 150,
                    'minheight' => 150
                    ))
                    ->setValueDisabled(true);
    //Attach element kedalam form
    $this->addElement($images);
```

//Other code goes here.....................

**And at PersonilController.php**

```
 public function createAction()
{
    $form = new Pengadilan_Form_PersonilCreate();
    $this->view->form = $form;
    $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger;

    //SImpan kedatabase
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
            $personil = new Pengadilan_Model_Personil();
            $personil->fromArray($form->getValues());
            $personil->RecordDate = date('Y-m-d', mktime());
            $personil->DisplayStatus = 0;
            $personil->DisplayUntil = null;
            $personil->save();
            $id = $personil->RecordId;

            if ($form->images->isUploaded()){
                $form->images->receive();                   
                $personilImages = '/images/personil/' . basename($form->images->getFileName());

            }
```

//Other code here.........

The images was succesful uploaded to destination folder, but I'm confusing how to display the images at my display.phtml

I'm using ZF 1.8 and Doctrine 1.2 
Thank you so much for your help...

Comment: @RockyFord I'm working on a live project that uses ZF 1.6 :S

Comment: @Songo I feel for you, but you wouldn't start a new project with 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination folder is underneath your web root (or symlinked to a folder underneath the web root), then it's just something like this in your `display.phtml`:

`<img src="<?= $this->baseUrl() ?>/path/to/your/image.jpg" />`

However, if the upload destination is *outside* the web root, then you will probably need a special controller to access those images and deliver them. Since this incurs the cost of a whole MVC dispatch cycle merely to deliver an image, it is typically reserved for those cases where you need to control access to the uploaded image.

Comment: Thank you for answering, just maybe more specifically the intent of my question is an image that is displayed in accordance with personnel data.
or is there any other solution, for example I create a table to its own image?

Comment: I looks like you are storing this image to a provide customization to a page or account. Associate the name of the image with that record and store the image somewhere accessible to the server. Then when recall that record you have the name of the file and just need to prepend the path to the file: `<img src="<?php '/prepend/path' . $this->imageName ?>" />`

Comment: David this dosen't seem to work. Is there someplace where we have to initialize the baseUrl. My img tag displays the correct path to the image but I keep getting controller not found errors. It's like the img tag is being ignored. image folder is in /public

Comment: got mine figured out, as usual it was my fault... typo

Comment: I'm trying to understand and follow the tutorial in this book,  as a beginner I have a lot of trouble but finally got the solution. but now I'm really hard to know the problem and the script wont't work properly.